# Using Package Installers behind company firewall

Tags: macos, terminal, firewall, proxy, package-management

Is there a more efficient way to use package installers behind a firewall than adjusting the proxy settings for each installer?

As of now, I'm using Ruby Gems, Bower, and NPM and it's a pain to reset everything individually when my password changes or there's an update to our settings.

I'm looking for a more centralized solution.

Answer (score 2):

The common answer is to setup a local proxy like [squidman](http://squidman.net/squidman/) or [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/), so your login/pass credentials are only stored in one place - and all of your CLI tools point at a local proxy:port.

You can also go to your network people (who think all your broken developer tools are a personal problem, not theirs) and point out that you're forced to hardcode your login and password (GASP!) not only all over your machine, your virtual machines, and even AWS instances...

And then it VERY MUCH becomes their problem. Auth proxies are so nineties!

Comment: Is there an idiots guide to squidman that you know of? Google is coming up short.